# select_related on django 2.1 not working

Tags: django, oracle, orm

I'm using Django 2.1 and Oracle 12C. From the django docs if we have something like:

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.fieldA, self.fieldB) #neither field is ever null

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    hometown = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return hometown.__str__()

class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and then do either:

`Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').all()`
`Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').filter(...)`

I get `Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>` 
Oddly, `Book.objects.select_related('author_hometown').get(pk=123)` works.
Also, **all** the queries work if I use Django 2.0 as opposed to 2.1. Can anybody help? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
added **str** methods to models 
Also, when I force evaluation of the problem queries I get `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`

Comment: Did you by any change have overwritten the `__str__` and/or `__repr__` of `City`, `Person` and/or `Book`? The problem is *not* with the `QuerySet` itself, but with the printing of it in the shell.

Comment: You're absolutely correct...I did overwrite those methods and when I comment them out everything works...but do you know why this is necessary with 2.1 and how I can overwrite the methods without the error?

Comment: I'm still not confident that this has anything to do with Django-2.1. I think if you make the very same query in 2.0, you will get the same errors. If you can share the relevant `__repr__` and/or `__str__`, I can perhaps try to help you finding the problem. It probably means you for example want to add a string and a `None` together (or something similar).

Comment: thanks for your help...I updated the models and added more info in the update section...what's weird is that when I switch virtual environments (from one with   Django 2.0 as opposed to Django 2.1, all other packages the same) the problem goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` indicates that the query which is being generated is pulling data from multiple tables, and that one of the fields, which is defined using the same name in more than one of the tables in the query, is being used within the query without have a table qualifier prepended to it. For example

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ITEM_NUMBER, ORDERED_COUNT
  FROM ORDER o
  INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL d
    ON d.ORDER_NUMBER = o.ORDER_NUMBER
```

would provoke the same error because `ORDER_NUMBER` exists on both tables, but is not qualified with `o.` or `d.` in the field list of the SELECT statement. Without seeing the generated query and your table definitions I can't say exactly what the problem is, but it's something similar to this.