# Django 2.1 and select_related()

Tags: django, oracle, orm, foreign-keys

This is a follow-up / clarification to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861289/select-related-on-django-2-1-not-working) question.

I'm using Django 2.1, Python 3.6, and Oracle 12c.

Suppose I have two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    modelB_field = ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    example_field = models.IntegerField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    example_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Then if I do

```
ModelA.objects.filter(...).select_related('modelB_field')
```

I get

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Three observations:

1. I only get the error if the field `example_field` is in both
   models...even though it is **not** the primary key of `ModelB`.
2. The query that Django generates works in sqldeveloper.
3. The code works if I use a virtualenv with Django 2.0 instead of Django

The docs don't indicate anything changed with `select_related` in Django 2.1.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the ORM. By defining this, you made a `JOIN`, but now Django apparently forgot to specify over what table it wants the `example_field`.

Comment: You can file a bug on https://code.djangoproject.com/

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case...thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, its a bug on django 2.1, try downgrading to 2.0...